# Cognos 10 Filtering a calculated measure

Tags: filter, calculated-columns, cognos-10

Using a Crosstab dimensional report I having issues filtering out a specific value that I am getting from my calculated measure:

I am using the following calculated measure in Reporting Studio to get the required output..

```
 ROUND(([A1_SCHEDQTY]+[B1_SCHEDQTY]) / ([A1_QTY]+[B1_QTY]) * 100, 1)
```

However, in a few cases I am getting an output of '/0' I am unable to filter this out.  I have tried using an IF statement, but I believe my syntax is incorrect.

```
IF (ROUND(([A1_SCHEDQTY]+[B1_SCHEDQTY]) / ([A1_QTY]+[B1_QTY]) * 100, 1) = '/0') THEN NULL ELSE ROUND(([A1_SCHEDQTY]+[B1_SCHEDQTY]) / ([A1_QTY]+[B1_QTY]) * 100, 1)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the divisor of the equation for 0 instead of checking the entire equation for '/0'.  If you check the entire equation, the divide by 0 still takes place.

Try this:

```
IF ([A1_QTY]+[B1_QTY] = 0) THEN (NULL) ELSE (ROUND(([A1_SCHEDQTY]+[B1_SCHEDQTY]) / ([A1_QTY]+[B1_QTY]) * 100, 1))
```

Comment: This did work successfully, thank you.  However the Parent and child relationship I had on my Drill down row no longer shows the previous aggregated average, it gives me the aggregated total.  Not sure how changing the column's calculation would effect a drill down (hierarchy member) row.

Comment: @user3208073 : You might want to post a new question for that.  I have similar issues with Cognos reporting against dimensional sources, so I won't be much help there.

Comment: JerseyMike,  is there any other way to remove the /0 from the calculation?  I feel that the IF statement is what is causing the issue around the aggregated calculation.

Comment: @user3208073 : Do you need to keep records that divide by 0?  If not, you could use the first part of the IF statement as a filter on the report, then remove the IF all together.  You can also try highlighting the column, then, from the menu, choose Data -> Suppress -> Suppression Options.  This panel allows you to suppress the divide by 0, however, I think it suppresses the entire row.